# which is the best 8+2 1 gbps ethernet switch controller?

Tags: ethernet, switch, microcontroller

i'm making a home-made ethernet switch but i need a controller chip for it. it should be 8+2 port, gigabit ethernet, managed and need not have poe. i would also like to have the datasheet. (rtl8370 has been rejected since i couldn't find it's datasheet. if you have, kindly share it with me).

Comment: Why not buy a switch from amazon (or a local webshop)?

Comment: @Irsu85 , i like making home-made stuff. if i can't find a chip for that, i would do what you said.